# How to count total of flags in pandas in each column dynamically?

Tags: pandas

How to count total of flags in pandas for each column **dynamically**? I have around 500 columns in the pandas dataframe and each columns have 0 and 1 as a values.

**I want to do something like this.**

**Dataframe**:

```
id|flag1|flag2|flag3|.....|flag500
1 |  0  |   1 |   0 |.....|   1
2 |  0  |   0 |   1 |.....|   0
3 |  0  |   0 |   0 |.....|   1
4 |  0  |   1 |   0 |.....|   1
5 |  0  |   0 |   0 |.....|   0
```

**Result Dataframe**

```
Flags|counts
flag1| 0
flag1| 2
flag1| 1
.
.
flag500|3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source DF

```
In [61]: df
Out[61]:
   id  flag1  flag2  flag3  flag500
0   1      0      1      0        1
1   2      0      0      1        0
2   3      0      0      0        1
3   4      0      1      0        1
4   5      0      0      0        0
```

Counting

```
In [64]: df.filter(like='flag').sum()
Out[64]:
flag1      0
flag2      2
flag3      1
flag500    3
dtype: int64
```

> is there way to get result as a dataframe?

```
In [66]: df.filter(like='flag').sum().rename_axis('Flags').reset_index(name='counts')
Out[66]:
     Flags  counts
0    flag1       0
1    flag2       2
2    flag3       1
3  flag500       3
```

Comment: is there way to get result as a dataframe?